# Can't compile a TCL object code, don't understand why?

Tags: oop, compilation, tcl

Managed to downsize the code to this below, any ideas?

```
oo::class create RQ1_AREA_MLIMS {
   method genMethodNameForCheckModelName ( model_name } {
  return "for${model_name}Sdevv"
   }
}
```

I get this message:

```
wrong # args: should be "oo::class create RQ1_AREA_MLIMS ?definitionScript?"
  while executing
"oo::class create RQ1_AREA_MLIMS {
   method genMethodNameForCheckModelName ( model_name } {
     return "for${model_name}Sdevv"
   }"
(file "poca.tcl" line 1)
invoked from within
```

I use Tcl 8.6
Thanks.

Comment: You're using an open *parenthesis* instead of a *brace* here: `method genMethodNameForCheckModelName ( model_name }`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

```
  method genMethodNameForCheckModelName ( model_name } {
```

The problem is this character:

```
  method genMethodNameForCheckModelName ( model_name } {
                                        ↑
```

That `(` should be a `{`; general basic Tcl syntax.

Comment: yeah, the font is horrible, and I forgot my glasses. Looks just like a curly brace...